# checking size of Polygon drawn with Leaflet l.draw.polyline

Tags: size, polygon, leaflet

I've made a website with Leaflet to draw polygons on an `OSM-Map`.

Now I want to check the size of the polygon, because the polygon must not exceed a defined size, for example, 5 square kilometers.

Does anyone have a good idea to check the size of the drawn polygon?

Answer (score 9):

I have used leaflet.draw ( https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw ) to draw a polygon.

And it has geodesicArea function.
Sample in 'draw:created'.

```
    map.on('draw:created', function (e) {
        var type = e.layerType,
            layer = e.layer;
            if (type === 'polygon') 
            {
                var area = L.GeometryUtil.geodesicArea(layer.getLatLngs())
                ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of any Leaflet plugins that can accomplish this for you. However, the algorithm to do so is not terribly complex. Check this website: http://www.mathopenref.com/coordpolygonarea2.html that contains the algorithm, and many visual examples as to how the algorithm actually works.

```
function polygonArea(X, Y, numPoints) 
{ 
  area = 0;         // Accumulates area in the loop
  j = numPoints-1;  // The last vertex is the 'previous' one to the first

  for (i=0; i<numPoints; i++)
    { area = area +  (X[j]+X[i]) * (Y[j]-Y[i]); 
      j = i;  //j is previous vertex to i
    }
  return area/2;
}
```

In order to use this algorithm with Leaflet polygons, you would iterate through the Polygon `polygon.getLatLngs()` in order to get all the lat/lon pairs. Put them into two separate arrays - one for X coordinates, one for Y coordinates. Use these as parameters to the function above, and for `numPoints` hand it the `polygon.getLatLngs().length`

As the webpage says, it doesn't matter where on the polygon path this starts. However, if you begin in a counter-clockwise order, your result will be negative. You can handle all cases by simply getting the absolute value of whatever this function returns.

Comment: The geodesicArea was failing for me with a Simple CRS map, this method however worked perfectly, so thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GeometryUtil.geodesicArea()` to the get the area like this:

```
let area = L.GeometryUtil.geodesicArea(layer.getLatLngs()[0]);
```